# My App needs to switch on mobile's GPS all the time, user should not be able to switch off the GPS

Tags: android, gps, google-schemas

Is there any possible way for an app being able to force an android mobile to switch on it's GPS all the time, as it needs to send GPS data of the device to a server 24/7.

I have tried to implement the automatically switching on GPS through three different ways, but in all 3, any time user can switch off the GPS , which is not the requirement of the Application.

Is there any way? or it's not at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

User has more permissions than your app and read about that [restrictions on oreo](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.html)

Comment: So, you are sure the answer is no? I'm not worried about Oreo right now versions from 4.4.X to 7.1.0 is the range.

Comment: maybe try start foreground service that listens status of GPS, and turns on if it disabled, but disallowing to user use his hardware, I suppose there need to do it with root permissions.

Comment: Rooting the devices is not the possibility. Thanks,